# Play Framework: Logging time

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

I've been using the Play Framework but like many things, I haven't come across in defining logging templates that add a timestamp to the log.
For services that handle many requests/Akka messages per minute, this renders the logging almost useless.
For example, we use the Play logger a bit like this;

```
Logger.error("could not fulfil request", someException)
```

Which is how the documentation goes. The documentation does specify, that it is possible to define your own logging headers like;

```
val exceptionLogger = Logger("exception")
// and then
exceptionLogger.error("while handling some/request", someException)
```

The log entries resulting from the above don't contain a timestamp of any sort;

```
[error] exception - while handling some/request ...
```

There's no mention of the time whatsoever. Now, a workaround (not the prettiest) is something like;

```
def exceptionLogger = {
    val dt = new DateTime
    Logger(s"$dt exception")
}
```

Which does the job, but I'm not convinced. Is there a better way to format Play's default logging behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Play uses Logback, you can configure the log format in `conf/logback.xml`.

The logs in `log/application.log` will have a date stamp by default by STDOUT will not.  Add `%date` to the pattern in the STDOUT appender.

```
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```